# Too few arguments to function Main(CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function view_new_declaration_1($id,$token=''){
    $this->isLoggedIn();
    $dec_info = $this->Model_admin->get_new_declaration_by_id($id)->row();
    $data_admin = array(
    'token' => $token,
    'admin_info' => $this->model->getAdminInfo($this->session->userdata('email'))->row(),
    'dec_info' => $dec_info,
    'ia' => $this->Model_admin->get_ia_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'ib' => $this->Model_admin->get_ib_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'ii' => $this->Model_admin->get_ii_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'iiia' => $this->Model_admin->get_iiia_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'iiib' => $this->Model_admin->get_iiib_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result()
    );

    $data_applicant = array(
            // get data using email
    'token' => $token,
    'applicant_info' => $this->model->getApplicantInfo($this->session->userdata('email'))->row(),
    'dec_info' => $dec_info,
    'ia' => $this->Model_admin->get_ia_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'ib' => $this->Model_admin->get_ib_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'ii' => $this->Model_admin->get_ii_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'iiia' => $this->Model_admin->get_iiia_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result(),
    'iiib' => $this->Model_admin->get_iiib_by_id($dec_info->prop_id)->result()
    );


    if ($this->session->userdata('position_id') == '2') { // Administrator
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header', $data_admin);
        $this->load->view('applicant/properties/view_new_declaration_1', $data_admin);
    }
    if ($this->session->userdata('position_id') == '3') { // Applicant
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header', $data_applicant);
        $this->load->view('applicant/properties/view_new_declaration_1', $data_applicant);
    }
     else {
        $this->logout();
    }
}
```

I'm just new in CodeIgniter
Please help. I'm so desperate. Thank you in advance
Wanna display the following info but that error message shows
What should I do?

Comment: The problem is not necessarily the code you show above. The problem is caused by the code that calls `view_new_declaration_1`. Show that code.

Answer (score 1):

Confusing for me as well at first.

Do:

`public function view_new_declaration_1($id=null,$token=null){`

This way if user visits `somesite.com/view_new_declaration_1` without `somesite.com/view_new_declaration_1/someid/sometoken` you won't get the too few error.

That being said you should still check that those parameters exist as they seem to be **required** for your code in a fashion like:

```
public function view_new_declaration_1($id=null,$token=null){
    if (is_null($id) || is_null($token)) {
        show_error('Missing parameters'); // exits
    }
    ...
}
```